# How to append to a nil object in Rails iterating through a loop?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, object, iterator

```
  @preComments = Comment.where(:resource_hash => resource_hash).sort(:created_at.desc).all
  @preComments.each do |comment|
    u = ::User.find_by_id comment.user_id
    p u
    @comments << @preComments
    p "HERE!!!!!"
  end
```

That's my code, but `@comments` isn't defined so I get an error:

> You have a nil object when you didn't expect it! You might have
>   expected an instance of Array. The error occurred while evaluating
>   nil.<<

If I create an array first, then my view can't read it. So how do I do this?

Comment: I answered below, but if you give a better description of what you're trying to achieve with `@preComments` vs `@comments`, there might be a better way.

Comment: Could you please give more detail why your view can't read @comments if you create an array first ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the first time you iterate, you want to create the @comments array (containing that item), but all subsequent times you want to push that item onto the existing array. There's probably a more elegant way to do this, but I generally just do this:

```
@comments ? @comments = [comment] : @comments << comment
```

Answer (score 0):

Create the array before the loop using `@comments = []`, then in the loop make sure you're using `@comments << comment`, not `@comments << @preComments`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must initialize array

```
@preComments = Comment.where(:resource_hash => resource_hash).sort(:created_at.desc).all
@comments = []
@preComments.each do |comment|
  u = ::User.find_by_id comment.user_id
  p u
  @comments << comment
  p "HERE!!!!!"
end
```

or when loop is finished then pass values of @preComments to @comments

```
@preComments = Comment.where(:resource_hash => resource_hash).sort(:created_at.desc).all
@preComments.each do |comment|
  u = ::User.find_by_id comment.user_id
  p u
  p "HERE!!!!!"
end
@comments = @preComments
```